# Db2 A memory allocation error has occurred, com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: SQLCODE=-83, DRIVER=3.65.77

Tags: db2, sqlexception, sqlcode

I am getting error from Db2 saying :

```
SQL Error [ ]: A memory allocation error has occurred.. SQLCODE=-83, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=3.65.77
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: A memory allocation error has occurred.. SQLCODE=-83, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=3.65.77
```

I  have tried and refer [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1014242) which match my error code but I am not getting any luck. In my local I am having `DB2v11.1_win64` Db2 server.

This is my local Db2 server. and I have java running 1.8. Its development environment.

Any one has idea please let me know.

Comment: Also you are using an old (out of support) jdbc driver dating from Db2 v10.1 fixpack 2. Many bugs fixed since then...

Comment: What statement do you run exactly? What's your db2 version and fixpack? What appears in the db2diag.log on the server when you run your statement?

Comment: I am runnning some ruandom query and suddely my local DB started giving this error.

Comment: db2jcc-10.1.jar and db2jcc_license_cu-10.1.jar is the driver I am using in my classpath.
But specific to 3.65.77 ? I did not understand your point or question.
I am sorry I am missing somethings? 
WRT to jdbc driver in log ? But I copy from my log and I map my calsspath in my dbeaver as DB client and in my code base as Jar of i have mentioned above.

Comment: The  conflicting information is that your question states you are running Db2 v11.1 on Windows and if that was true then your jdbc 3.0 driver would report version 3.71.22 OR HIGHER.  But instead you are using the out of date v10.1 jar files (which report 3.65.77 version).  You should use instead the V11.1 jdbc drivers which are already installed on your system , because that is more likely to resolve your issues.